# Evaluating a the value of a formula that has been moved with its references

Tags: excel, vba

Consider a Cell with a formula in `Range("A1")` with references. If the cell is moved to `Range("B1")`, then so will the formula with its references.

How do I evaluate the result of this moved formula **in a UDF function**, where its only parameter is `Range(“A1”)`?

As a concrete example, consider:

`Range("A1").Formula = XLOOKUP(G$6, $C$4:$W$4, $C$21:$W$21,0)`

If the formula is moved to `B1` it becomes

`Range("B1").Formula = XLOOKUP(H$6, $C$4:$W$4, $C$21:$W$21,0)`

I can then run `Evaluate(Range("B1").Formula)` within a UDF function and receive the required result.

How do I perform all of this in a UDF function?

I've tried Googling, and going through Excel's API. I've even referred to R1C1 - but the function keeps failing.

Comment: "In a function" means in a worksheet function, or in a VBA UDF ?

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams - yes VBA UDF. I've tried to clarify this in my email. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there's any non-complex way to do this: you'd need to parse out the various input ranges (assuming none of them are named ranges) then figure out which of them are relative vs. absolute, apply the required offset, then evaluate the modified formula.

Comment: @TimWilliams - Indeed; I figured that much upon my attempt. A UDF Function restricts working with other cells, thereby removing the use of RC referencing (which easily solves the issue, but only in a sub procedure). I will leave this question open incase someone has an idea.